# My ionic2 calendar doesn't load the event on the calendar, please any idea?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular8

i'm using ionic2calendar i'm trying to load the event on the calendar
but it doesnt work i don't understand where is the problem
i'm trying to load it like this now, because i use symfony on the backend, so if it work like this, i'll get the dates from symfony's database
needhelp thank you for your help

**planning.page.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {BehaviorSubject, Subscription} from "rxjs";
import {AuthentificationService} from "../../shared/authentification.service";
import {Planning} from "../consultant/modele/Planning";
import {ShiftService} from "../../shared/shift.service";
import {AlertService} from "../../shared/alert.service";
import {NativeTransitionOptions} from "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions";
import {NativePageTransitions} from "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions/ngx";
import {Platform} from "@ionic/angular";
import {CalendarComponent} from "ionic2-calendar";

registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr');
@Component({
  selector: 'app-planning',
  templateUrl: './planning.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./planning.page.scss'],
})
export class PlanningPage {
  private refreshAutomatique: Subscription;
  private monPlanning: Planning = new Planning();
  private hasPlanning: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  private delaisRetard: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  private options: NativeTransitionOptions;
  private startTime = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 7, 28));
  private endTime = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 7, 28));

  currentDate = new Date();
  currentMonth: string;
  eventSource;
  @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) myCalendar: CalendarComponent;

  showAddEvent: boolean;
  newEvent = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    startTime: new Date().toISOString(),
    endTime: new Date().toISOString()
  };
  allEvents = [];
  constructor(private route: Router,
              private platform: Platform,
              private myRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private authentificationService: AuthentificationService,
              private alertService: AlertService,
              private shiftService: ShiftService,
              private nativePageTransitions: NativePageTransitions) {
  //  this.loadEvents();
    this.refreshAutomatique = this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
      this.getShiftAndProfil();
    });
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.options = {
      direction: 'left',
      duration: 400,
      slowdownfactor: -1,
      iosdelay: 50
    };
    this.getShiftAndProfil();
  }
  onViewTitleChanged(title: string) {
    this.currentMonth = title;
  }

  showHideForm(){
    this.showAddEvent = !this.showAddEvent;
  }
  addEvent() {
    this.allEvents.push({
      title: this.newEvent.title,
      startTime:  new Date(this.newEvent.startTime),
      endTime: new Date(this.newEvent.endTime),
      description: this.newEvent.description,
    });
    this.showHideForm();
  }


  loadEvents() {
    this.eventSource.push({
      title: 'test',
      startTime: new Date('July 17, 2020 03:24:00'),
     // startTime: this.startTime,
      //endTime: this.endTime,
      endTime: new Date('July 17, 2020 05:24:00'),
      allDay: false
    });
    this.myCalendar.loadEvents();
  }


  ionViewWillEnter() {
    if (this.monPlanning.poste === "") {
      this.getShiftAndProfil();
    }
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.monPlanning = new Planning();
  }

  private getShiftAndProfil() {
    this.shiftService.getShift().subscribe(
        data => {
          this.hasPlanning.next(data["code"] !== 404);
          if (this.hasPlanning.getValue()) {
            this.shiftService.idShift = data["idShift"];
            this.monPlanning = new Planning(new Date(data["start"]["date"]),
                new Date(data["end"]["date"]),
                data["poste"],
                data["isBackup"],
                data["isActive"],
                data["state"],
                data["backup_state"]);
            if (!data["isBackup"] && data["backup"] === undefined) {
              localStorage.setItem("userIdConsultant", data["consultant"]);
            }
            if (data["isBackup"] && !isNaN(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("userIdConsultant")))) {
              localStorage.removeItem("userIdConsultant");
            }
            this.shiftService.consultantIsBackUp = isNaN(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("userIdConsultant")));
            console.log('condition 1' + !isNaN(data["backup"]));
            console.log('condition 1' + localStorage.getItem("userIdConsultant") !== undefined);
            console.log('consultant is bakcup' + this.shiftService.consultantIsBackUp);
            console.log('session' + localStorage.getItem("userIdConsultant"));
            console.log('backup' + data["isBackup"]);
            this.shiftService.isActivatedBackUp = data["isActive"];
            console.log('backupactove' + this.shiftService.isActivatedBackUp);
            this.delaisRetard.next(parseInt(
                localStorage.getItem("delaisRetard") !== null && this.monPlanning.state === 3 ?
                    localStorage.getItem("delaisRetard") : "0"));
            if (this.monPlanning.state !== 3) {
              localStorage.removeItem("delaisRetard");
            }
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.error(error);
          this.hasPlanning.next(error.status < 400)
        }
    );
  }


  private getShiftsAndProfil() {
    this.shiftService.getAllShift().subscribe(
        data => {
          this.hasPlanning.next(data["code"] !== 404);
          if (this.hasPlanning.getValue()) {
            this.shiftService.idShift = data["idShift"];
            this.monPlanning = new Planning(new Date(data["start"]["date"]),
                new Date(data["end"]["date"]),
                data["poste"],
                data["isBackup"],
                data["isActive"],
                data["state"],
                data["backup_state"]);
            if (!data["isBackup"] && data["backup"] === undefined) {
              localStorage.setItem("userIdConsultant", data["consultant"]);
            }
            if (data["isBackup"] && !isNaN(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("userIdConsultant")))) {
              localStorage.removeItem("userIdConsultant");
            }
            this.shiftService.consultantIsBackUp = isNaN(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("userIdConsultant")));
            console.log('condition 1' + !isNaN(data["backup"]));
            console.log('condition 1' + localStorage.getItem("userIdConsultant") !== undefined);
            console.log('consultant is bakcup' + this.shiftService.consultantIsBackUp);
            console.log('session' + localStorage.getItem("userIdConsultant"));
            console.log('backup' + data["isBackup"]);
            this.shiftService.isActivatedBackUp = data["isActive"];
            console.log('backupactove' + this.shiftService.isActivatedBackUp);
            this.delaisRetard.next(parseInt(
                localStorage.getItem("delaisRetard") !== null && this.monPlanning.state === 3 ?
                    localStorage.getItem("delaisRetard") : "0"));
            if (this.monPlanning.state !== 3) {
              localStorage.removeItem("delaisRetard");
            }
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.error(error);
          this.hasPlanning.next(error.status < 400)
        }
    );
  }

  ionRefresh(event) {
    console.log('Pull Event Triggered!');
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      this.getShiftAndProfil();
      //complete()  signify that the refreshing has completed and to close the refresher
      event.target.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }

  ionPull(event) {
    //Emitted while the user is pulling down the content and exposing the refresher.
    console.log('ionPull Event Triggered!');
  }

  ionStart(event) {
    //Emitted when the user begins to start pulling down.
    console.log('ionStart Event Triggered!');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.refreshAutomatique.unsubscribe();
  }

  /* loadEvent() {
    this.shiftService.getShift().subscribe(data => {

      this.allEvents = [];
      this.allEvents.push({
        startTime: new Date('July 17, 2020 03:24:00'),
        endTime: new Date('July 17, 2020 05:24:00'),
        title : 'hello',
        description : 'hello'
      });
      this.myCalendar.loadEvents();
      console.log('Poste: ' +new Date('July 17, 2020 03:24:00'));

       console.log('Poste: ' +new Date(this.monPlanning.dateDebut)+ '' +new Date(this.monPlanning.dateFin)+ '');

  //    this.allEvents.push({
    //  dateFin: new Date(this.monPlanning.dateFin),
      //});
    });
  }

*/

  displayActionButton = (): boolean => ([0, 3].some(_ => _ === this.monPlanning.state) && !this.shiftService.consultantIsBackUp)
      || (0 === this.monPlanning.backUpState && this.shiftService.consultantIsBackUp)
}
```

**planning.page.html**

```
  <calendar *ngIf="!showAddEvent" id="myCalendar"
            [eventSource]="eventSource"
            locale="fr-FR"
            calendarMode="month"
            startHour="6"
            endHour="20"
            step="30"
            startingDayWeek="1"
            [currentDate]="currentDate"
            (onTitleChanged)="onViewTitleChanged($event)">
  </calendar>
```